# Truncate text and link to Read more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

Come across a little stumbling block when linking to a post within my app. I am truncating the text of a post and providing a 'Read More' link. There are 2 areas where posts are viewed, one  for everyone ( public) and also one for the admin user to edit/delete posts.

So in my public view I am doing this

```
<% @toppost.each do |t| %>
    <div class="post-item">
      <h2><%= t.title %></h2>
       <ul id="newsHome">
        <li><%= date_output(t.published_on) %></li>
        <li><%= t.department.name %></li>
        <li>by Admin</li>
       </ul>
       <% if t.comments.length > 350 %>
        <p class="post-description"><%= truncate(t.comments, length: 350).html_safe %>
        <%= link_to '...Read more', t %></p>
        <% else %>
        <p class="post-description"><%= t.comments.html_safe %></p>

       <% end %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

However when clicking read more it takes me to the url

```
/posts/:id
```

which is actually the place where an admin user views posts, so at the moment a user will get redirected back to the home page as the posts controller has

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

The place where all posts are viewed publicly are on specific news pages , for example

```
localhost:3000/tynewyddnews
localhost:3000/woodside
localhost:3000/sandpiper
localhost:3000/outreach
```

My question is how to link to that post at its location in the public part of the site.

Index action where top_posts method used(see below for method)

```
def index 
@title = 'Home'
@toppost = Post.top_posts
```

end

top_posts method

```
def self.top_posts
#Array with each of the 4 departments - first record
top_posts = [
  self.tynewydd_posts.first,
  self.woodside_posts.first,
  self.sandpiper_posts.first,
  self.outreach_posts.first
]
#remove entry if nil
top_posts.delete_if {|x| x==nil}
return top_posts
```

end

Controller

```
def tynewyddnews
  @title = 'Ty Newydd News'
  tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts.reverse
  tynewyddpost.pop
  @tynewyddpost = tynewyddpost
  @tynewyddpostlatest = Post.tynewydd_posts.first
end
```

Model

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
```

There are another 3 scopes for the other departments, all the same looking for the condition department name

Hopefully ive added enough info, anything else needed please ask

EDIT

Been thinking this through and not sure if im on right track, but for each post i need it to link to its appropriate news page in the public pages controller.

```
tynewyddnews
sandpipernews
outreachnews
Woodsidenews
```

So in my link_to i need to pass a route to the appropriate action depending upon the type of post.. so how to give each post a type and then link to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wow, ok, where do I begin.

You need a route that points to that controller action, for example

```
`get '/tynewyddnews' => 'news#tynewyddnews', :as => 'public_news' # gives you the route public_news_path
```

in your view

```
= link_to 'Read More', public_news_path
```

So ya, that should do it. BTW you can also use the `.truncate()` method. You pass in the length as an argument, and it adds the `...` for you

Comment: thank you, i have updated question as not sure if was clear enough.In the index action I show the latest post from a news section, there are 4. How do i set the path to go to the paticular post depending upon which is clicked, it could go to any one of the 4. the way you describe gives me one specfic path, though thats probably my fault for not being clear enough

Comment: What's preventing you from using an if/else statement?

Comment: unsure what i would select by, ie the params to choose, so if params[:?] link_to 'newspath'